# Angular ngfor set empty grid if condition matches

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looping an array which it's length could change on a three column row ( on desktop view.

**html**

```
<div  class="row" >
  <div *ngFor="let indicator of fiveElements; let index = index"
    class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 pb-4 pl-3 pr-3 indicatorContainer">
    <div>{{index}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
fiveElements = [1,2,3,4,5]

}
```

I would that when the array length is equal to 4 the third column is empty

Here's a schema to explain

[image: empty grid]

Here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-ku8frn)

Comment: Use ``*ngIf`` to test the length of your array and do what you want

Comment: I have updated my demo, hope is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>If I understood your question right - I would do it like this:</s>

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let indicator of fourElements; let index = index" class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 pb-4 pl-3 pr-3 indicatorContainer">
        <div *ngIf="index !== 3 && fourElements.length === 4">{{index}}</div>
        <!--- third column should get empty -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for clarification - now I know what you  want :)
You can achieve this by using the longhand syntax for ngFor:

```
<div class="row">
        <ng-template ngFor let-indicator [ngForOf]="fourElements" let-index="index">
            <div *ngIf="index === 2 && fourElements.length === 4" class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 pb-4 pl-3 pr-3 indicatorContainer">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 pb-4 pl-3 pr-3 indicatorContainer">
                <div>{{index+1}}</div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </div>
```

Comment: This will hide third element, What I would is to push only have two elements in the first line + empty column and two elements in the next line

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to understand the diferrence betweek *ngfor and ngForOf,
if I use your solution with *ngfor that does not work , why ?

Comment: *ngFor is just the shorthand syntax for cleaner code - in the end it does the same. The problem with *ngFor in your situation is that you define the for loop on the div element. But you want to add a div on the same level between one loop - this only can work when the parent of the div is looping through.
With the longhand syntax you define it on the parent ng template and so you have more control over it and can place another div with an if condition. I hope you understand the difference.
Docs: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description